# How i can implement search field inside a ng-zorro filter

Tags: angular, typescript, filter, ng-zorro-antd

I implemented the filter for each column of the table using Ng-Zorro.
The problem arises when I have a very long filter list and I would like to insert a search field in which to filter the filter list.

How i can do?

My filter impementation is:

```
  <th scope="col" nz-th nzShowFilter [nzFilters]="listOfProjects" (nzFilterChange)="filter($event,'projects')">Projects</th>
```

[EXAMPLE OF MY FILTER LIST IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgXS2.png)

Comment: What it does ? Is there any lags or it doesn't show?

Comment: the filter shows me many checkboxes because I have many elements. Is there a way to insert a search field within this downmenu in order to filter within the filter list?. unfortunately I can't find a way to also insert a search field within NZFilter to filter within the filter list.

Comment: I can' just imagine what is causing an issue? Can you share some code or visuals?

Comment: I do not have any problem.
I would simply like to know if there was a way to add a search field within the filter list that I have implemented with the above code.
In fact if you see the post image, I have a long list. I would like a search field within that would allow me to search within it.

Comment: i must use Ng-Zorro component, so i don't know how i can do